# Parse json body array sent in POST request and print

Tags: json, go, encoding-json-go

I am having one issue while reading the json array. Need help for below query.

Request Json :

```
{ "httpReq": {
"username": "1234567890",
"password": "1234567890",
"number": "123456"
}
}
```

Response Json :

```
{ "httpResp": {
    "status": "Pass",
    "message": "great"
    }
    }
```

Below was my code: If i am passing the json object below its working, but i need to send "httpReq" in json.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


type people struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
    
}

type peopleread struct {
    Collection []people
}

func main() {
    text := `{
    "username": "1234567890",
    "password": "1234567890",
    "number": "123456"
    
}`
    textBytes := []byte(text)

    //people1 := people{}
    var people2 people
    err := json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &people2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    Username := people2.Username
    Password := people2.Password
    Number := people2.Number
        fmt.Println(Username)
        fmt.Println(Password)
        fmt.Println(Number) 
}
```

Comment: Look at the contents of `textBytes` and compare to your original text, you're not handling the `httpReq` field which contains the data you care about.

Comment: your struct is not right, if you wanted to unmarshal the type of json in your request, you would need a struct of type `struct{HttpReq people\`json:"httpReq"\`}`and use that in unmarshalling `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: [The language is called Go](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/30wsrs/the_name_of_our_language_is_go/). Not GOlang, not Go Lang, not golang.  Just Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unmarshal with `httpReq` field you have to handle this.

Create a struct to your wrap your request body like json

```
type HttpReq struct{
   HttpReq people `json:"httpReq"`
}
```

Then use unmarshal

```
var httpReq HttpReq
err := json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &httpReq)
```

Full code in Go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/gpyc25kAKhd)

Comment: Could you help me in sending the response json also. { "httpResp": {
    "status": "Pass",
    "message": "great"
    }
    }

Comment: type Response struct {
 Success string `json:"success"`
 Message  string    `json:"message"`
}

type HTTPResp struct {
 Userresp []Response `json:"httpResp"`
}

respData := HTTPResp{}
str := Reponse{"Success", "Great!"}
respData.HTTPResp = append(respData.HTTPResp,str)

b, _ := json.Marshal(respData)
respbody := string(b)
c.String(http.StatusOK, respbody)

Comment: I am getting this error "first argument to append must be slice; have struct { Sucess string "json:\"success\""; Message string "json:\"message\"" }"

Comment: Don't use slice `[]Response`, use `Response` in `HTTPResp` struct and set as `respData.Userresp = str`

Comment: What do you mean by update. I have already accepted your answer

Comment: I can't upvote the question as it was raised by me :(. Please guide me how to do that

Comment: Please read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments